# @StateObject inside NavigationLinks' destination view works strange

Tags: swiftui, observedobject

I'm trying to figured out how @StateObject works in swiftUI.
As per documentation documantation(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject):

> SwiftUI creates a new instance of the object only once for each instance of the structure that declares the object

So i wrote simple exaple:

```swift
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var counter: Int = 0

    init() {
        print("init called")
    }
}

struct Counter: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(model.counter)")
            Button(action: {
                self.model.counter+=1
            }, label: {
                Text("Button")
            })
        }

        
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var model = [1]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                List(model, id: \.self) { i in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: Counter(),
                        label: {
                            Text("\(i)")
                        })
                }
                Button(action: {
                    model.append(2)
                }, label: {
                    Text("Button")
                })
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

But if i navigate to Counter, push button several times and navigate back and forth again, my value is dropped, and console shows, that initializer of @StataObject was called twice. So it seems like Counter() is recreated each time i navigate to it.

And my first question is how to prevent NavigationView to do so? How to tell it, that my Counter is the same and should not be recreated from scratch?

Second problem shows up when i change @StateObject to @ObservedObject. In this case app works as i planned: Counter stores count value. But if i tap on button at the botom of the screen and add new element to list, all list entities get recreated and console shows multiply "init" logs. Counter also is dropped at this point. How it intends to work at all?

Comment: The key word in your problem is "stores" `@StateObject` is not storage. It hold values but only while the `View` is active. If the `View` is deinitialized it get re-initialized when it is called again. If you want to "store" the value you will have to use some kind of storage such as a database, file, etc. You can put the `@StateObject` in the `ContentView` and pass it as an `environmentObject` if you want it to last a little longer.

Comment: Important part here is *once for each instance* - when you navigate the new instance of `Counter` is created, so behaviour is as documented.